# Regex Rewrite AND pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like to create a regular expression for rewrite.

Rewrite all request to index.php (no need match), which not starts with /api, or not finish with ( '.html', or '.js' or '.css' or '.png')

My example is yet this, but do not working well:

```
(!^/api|!\\.html$|!\\.js$|!\\.css$|!\\.png$) /index.html [L]
```

Example:

```
/a/b/c.css -> not rewrite
/a/b/c -> rewrite
/api/something -> not rewrite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply do this:

```
RewriteRule !(^/api.*|.*\.(html|png|js|css)$) /index.php [L]
```

See information about using the `NOT` (`!`) operator [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)